# Can numpy accept pointer from c/c++?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to prepare data for numpy from c/c++ side. I wonder whether numpy supports discrete data that each of its row or column is contiguous but the rows/columns are not contiguous, so that I could prepare data from c/c++ side as pointers that pointers to the data of each row/column and merely pass these pointers to numpy to compose its array values ?

Comment: What does **"each of its row or column is contiguous but the rows/columns are not contiguous"** mean? Also, are you talking about passing pointers in-memory?

Comment: The data buffer of a `ndarray` is one contiguous c array.

Comment: @Vishnudev It means that the memory of an array is not contiguous, so that I can use different pointers to refer each row/

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray  "An instance of class ndarray consists of a contiguous one-dimensional segment of computer memory (owned by the array, or by some other object),"

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the problem can be solved using [Boost Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/index.html)?
And generally keeping your data contiguous is beneficial for most functions.